# Border around row spanned table

Tags: html, css

Hello I have created table using `td` and `row span`. Now I want to make the structure clearer by bolding the major category as such

[image]

https://plnkr.co/edit/4JM61bhjSqWR512PaWcS?p=preview

How can I achieve this?
I fear that I have to manually color each cell boarder one by one? It seems that boarder and coloring attribute either concern td or tr element. Hence is it possible to span such effect across column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
<tbody>
  <tr class="colored">
    <td rowspan="6">A</td>
    <td rowspan="3">B</td>
    <td>C</td>
    <td> Input</td>
    <td> Input</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>D</td>
    <td> Input</td>
    <td> Input</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>E</td>
    <td> Input</td>
    <td> Input</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="colored">
    <td rowspan="3">B</td>
    <td>F</td>
    <td> Input</td>
    <td> Input</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>G</td>
    <td> Input</td>
    <td> Input</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>H</td>
    <td> Input</td>
    <td> Input</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
<tbody>
  <tr class="colored">
    <td rowspan="6">A</td>
    <td rowspan="4">B</td>
    <td>C</td>
    <td> Input</td>
    <td> Input</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>D</td>
    <td> Input</td>
    <td> Input</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>E</td>
    <td> Input</td>
    <td> Input</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>F</td>
    <td> Input</td>
    <td> Input</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="colored">
    <td rowspan="2">B</td>
    <td>G</td>
    <td> Input</td>
    <td> Input</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>H</td>
    <td> Input</td>
    <td> Input</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

and this css :

```
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

tbody .colored td[rowspan]:not(:first-child) {
  border-left: 2px solid red;
  border-top: 2px solid red;
  border-bottom: 2px solid red;
}

tbody .colored td:nth-of-type(n+2) {
  border-top: 2px solid red;
}

tbody tr td:last-child {
  border-right: 2px solid red;
}

tbody tr:last-child td:nth-child(n+1) {
  border-bottom: 2px solid red;
}
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/VYFXhZf0fnZqmr1BN1z6?p=preview

Comment: it's not a clean solution I mean, but I think it fixes your issue. I'll try to use more css classes to design the borders

Comment: Thank you! when you specified 2,3,4 rowspan. Is that bruteforce? I will have a dynamic data (longer table etc.) but the structure does not change, will it work then?

Comment: yes it is! but if the structure remains the same so all the cells with rowspan 2, 3 and 4 will have a border, so this won't be a problem.

Comment: I see! Is it possible to make it generally and not stick to only 2,3,4. Sometimes myrow span go up to 20+ haha. My table is dynamic

Comment: ok try this: https://plnkr.co/edit/VYFXhZf0fnZqmr1BN1z6?p=preview. This selects all td with rowspan attribute exept the first cells in every row. I hope this helps

Comment: Thank you so much! however, there is a few bug, I updated my plunkr and you can see some line is not drawn! I am playing around with css but I am quite confused right now!

Comment: I have updated my plunkr and it is perfectly working now! Thank you for giving me a head start